# Blending images in Metal

Tags: macos, metal

I've been trying to learn Metal and have become stuck when trying to blend two images together.

I've got two, textured quads with the opacity of one set to 0.5 and it's scaled to 75% of the other's size.

The quads are:

[image]

and

[image]

The MTKView is cleared with red. When I try to blend them the result is:

[image]

what I'm expecting is:

[image]

For my pipeline setup I'm using:

```
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
descriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

The Metal shader functions are:

```
vertex VertexOut vertex_shader(const VertexIn vertex_in [[ stage_in ]], constant ModelMatrix &matrix [[ buffer(1) ]], constant const UniformsStruct &uniforms [[ buffer(2) ]]) {
    VertexOut vertex_out;
    vertex_out.position = matrix.mvpMatrix * vertex_in.position;
    vertex_out.colour = vertex_in.colour;
    vertex_out.textureCoordinates = vertex_in.textureCoordinates;
    vertex_out.opacity = uniforms.opacity;
    return vertex_out;
}

fragment half4 masked_textured_fragment_shader(VertexOut vertex_from_vertex_shader [[ stage_in ]], sampler sampler2d [[ sampler(0) ]], texture2d<float> mask [[ texture(1) ]], texture2d<float> texture [[ texture(0) ]]) {
    float4 keyPixel = mask.sample(sampler2d, vertex_from_vertex_shader.textureCoordinates);
    float4 colour = texture.sample(sampler2d, vertex_from_vertex_shader.textureCoordinates);
    return half4(colour.r * keyPixel.r, colour.g * keyPixel.g, colour.b * keyPixel.b, vertex_from_vertex_shader.opacity);
}
```

My current best guess is the pipeline isn't set with the correct options but changing them doesn't make the two quads blend but does give some interesting effects!

Answer (score 2):

Setting the correct pipeline state for the second quad is the only thing you have to do to achieve blending - you don’t have to do any calculations in the fragment function.

Try setting up one simple pipeline with none of the blending for the back quad.
Then set up the pipeline as you have above for the front quad.

When you render the two quads, switch the pipeline state so the back quad renders without blending and the front quad renders with blending.

[image: blending]

to get the above result, this is my fragment function for both quads:

```
fragment float4 fragment_main (VertexOut in [[ stage_in ]],
                   texture2d<float> texture [[ texture(0) ]]) {
  constexpr sampler sampler2d;
  float4 color = texture.sample(sampler2d, in.textureCoordinates);
  color.a = 0.5;  // set opacity. Ignored if blending is not enabled
  return color;
}
```

This is “fixed function” blending - you set the state of the GPU to blend by the use of two different pipeline states.

You can read more about it at [Metal By Example](http://metalbyexample.com/translucency-and-transparency/)